# Align two 3D datasets

Tags: matlab, point-clouds

I am working on a problem where I am trying to align two datasets.

1. The issue is that the data order is not known. Below is a sample code where I am trying to align data1 and data3.
2. The second issue is when the number of points in both the datasets are not equal.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
rng(11);
N = 10 %10 points
data1 = randn(10,3); %10 coordinates
order = randperm(N)
data2 = data1(order,:); %Reordered data

%Rotation matrix and translation vector
rotM = [0.5771    0.1728    0.7982;
   -0.4940    0.8521    0.1728;
   -0.6503   -0.4940    0.5771]
TT = [1 2 3];

data3 = data2*rotM + TT;
```

Edit: Align = rotate and transform `data3` to recover `rotM` and `T`.

Comment: What do you mean by "align" the datasets? Do you want them to somehow share an origin? Please provide more details, and what you've tried already to solve the problem.

Comment: Why is this tagged Python?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is a point cloud registration. And PC registration cares little about the order of points.

Assuming you are using Matlab, you could check the below website for the Matlab ICP algorithm. https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcregistericp.html

And

```matlab
rotM = tform.R;
TT = tform.Translation ;
```